# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.msgpack.template.TemplateRegistry Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

Hi im working in Android Studio with org.msgpack:msgpack:0.6.12,
the app compiles but in runtime, show me this exepction:

> Process: com.procibernetica.moca, PID: 10164
>                                                                            java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.msgpack.template.TemplateRegistry
>                                                                                at org.msgpack.MessagePack.(MessagePack.java:60)

```
My grade:

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.procibernetica.moca"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
   buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'

    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'

        compile 'org.msgpack:msgpack:0.6.12'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'

    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.0.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile project(':moca-sdk-android-1.9.6')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

My structure

[image]

Comment: Could you share your project structure?

Comment: when you my project structure, refer to LIBS and packages?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: with screenshot is right?

Answer (score 0):

I can see now, you have an extension of type .aar there, not .jar, try to download the moca-sdk.jar, if you can't find it or whatever, try this:

```
dependencies {
   compile(name:'moca-sdk-android-1.9.6', ext:'aar')
 }
repositories{
      flatDir{
              dirs 'libs'
       }
 }
```